# In R geomtextpath, does it's not support chinese

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Does ‘geom_textpath’ not support Chinese ? As below sample, when using geom_textpath add label to the plot, it's only show englise letters. Anyone can help? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geomtextpath)
plot_data_2 <- data.frame(category=c('品类A','品类B','品类C','品类D'),
                          amount=c(1,6,4,7))

plot_data_2 %>% ggplot(aes(x=1,y=amount,fill=category))+
  geom_col()+geom_textpath(position = position_stack(vjust=0.5),
                           aes(label=category))+
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrew. I'm one of the authors of geomtextpath. We didn't test for Chinese character support during development, so the answer is "probably not". However, this is something we can look at implementing in the next release. I will open a new issue. In the meantime, could I ask whether you have tried using different fonts?

Comment: @Allan  I tried family "Noto Sans TC" and it's can curve chinese. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the other author of {geomtextpath}.

This is a font fallback issue. Smart text renderers try to lookup a particular glyph from a font file, and if they don't find it, they substitute the font with another that does have the glyph. Because {geomtextpath} has to do a 'convert font index back to glyph' step, fallback doesn't work.

In this case, the best course of action would be to explicitly use a font that supports Chinese characters. The freely available ['Noto Sans TC'](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+TC?query=noto+sans) or ['Noto Sans Simplified Chinese'](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+SC?query=noto+sans) fonts should work, though I don't know whether traditional or simplified is more appropriate here.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geomtextpath)

# Didn't reprex well because glyphs below get substituted by `??`.
plot_data_2 <- data.frame(category=c('品类A','品类B','品类C','品类D'),
                          amount=c(1,6,4,7))

plot_data_2 %>% ggplot(aes(x=1,y=amount,fill=category))+
  geom_col()+geom_textpath(position = position_stack(vjust=0.5),
                           aes(label=category),
                           family = "Noto Sans TC")+
  coord_polar() +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(family = "Noto Sans TC"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's great! After installed the family, geomtextpath can use for Chinese now.